# Spring Boot data-jpa and nativeQuery Postgres cast

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, casting

I have a custom `@Query` in a repository that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM topicaudit_c14001 
WHERE auditdate >= NOW() 
AND auditdate <= NOW() + '1 hour'::INTERVAL 
AND accepted_status = 'ACCEPTED' 
AND reminder_sent = FALSE
```

When I run this, I get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: 
Not all named parameters have been set: [:INTERVAL]
```

Obviously it is interpreting the `::INTERVAL` cast (Postgresql) as a named parameter and cannot fire the query since I don't provide a parameter.

How can I write this query so that it works with JPA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it out shortly after posting. Escaping the `::` helps.

```
SELECT * FROM topicaudit_c14001 
WHERE auditdate >= NOW() 
AND auditdate <= NOW() + '1 hour'\\:\\:INTERVAL 
AND accepted_status = 'ACCEPTED' 
AND reminder_sent = FALSE
```