# Convert VARCHAR to INT/NUMBER in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a table `ACTIVITIES_T` in a PostgreSQL DB. `ACTIVITY_CODE` is a `VARCHAR` column:

```
ID (INT)  |  ACTIVITY_CODE (VARCHAR) | ACTIVITY_TEXT (VARCHAR)
-------------------------------------------------------------
..            ..                      ..
7             10012                   ..
8             10013                   ..
9             10014                   ..
10            10015                   ..
11            SPECIAL                 ..
```

I have a contiguous block of pseudo-numbers, `10012..10015`, that I need to select with the `BETWEEN a AND b` operator, or `>= n1 and <= n2`.

But not all entries in `ACTIVITY_CODE` are numeric values.
I tried this:

```
select * from activities_t  where activity_code::int >= 10012 and 
                                  activity_code::int <= 10015;
```

but got the error

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: SPECIAL
> ```

Comment: 'SPECIAL' is text. Casting as integer throws an error. Try using     `substring(activity_code FROM '\d+')::int` instead of `activity_code::int`

Comment: What if I actually want to exclude all non-numerics? Is there is a CASE IS NUMERIC I can use? I don't want to substring, in case there's a `SPECIAL10012` that I want to exclude also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   activities_t
WHERE  CASE WHEN activity_code ~ '^\d+$'  -- only digits
            THEN activity_code::int BETWEEN 10012 AND 10015 END;
```

The [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) wrapper avoids the exception. Only strings consisting of only digits are considered. (So no blank-padding either!)
No `ELSE` needed because `CASE` defaults to `NULL` and only `TRUE` qualifies in the `WHERE` clause.

Of course, this cannot use any plain index on `activity_code`.

If you need better **performance**, either clean up your your table design or, if that's not an option, create an expression index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON activities_t((CASE WHEN activity_code ~ '^\d+$'
                                           THEN activity_code::int END));
```

And match the expression in your query:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN activity_code ~ '^\d+$' THEN activity_code::int END
FROM   activities_t
WHERE  CASE WHEN activity_code ~ '^\d+$'
            THEN activity_code::int END BETWEEN 10012 AND 10015;
```

This is slightly different than the first query, and would be slightly more expensive if it wouldn't trigger an index scan.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what **@Erwin Brandstetter** wrote, if using this in Spring Data, there will be complaints about using the `::` operator from your @Query.

To fix that, escape the `::` as shown in this example,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43982706/1005607

```
\\:\\:
```

Or alternatively modify the query to use the `cast` function.

```
@Query(value="select * from activities_t where " + 
             "   case when  activity_code ~ '^\d+$' " +  // only digits   
             "   then cast(activity_code as int) between 10012 and 10015 end ", 
       nativeQuery=true)
public List<ActivityT> getByActivityCodes();
```