# ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @> character varying

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

When I am executing the below query in PGAdmin, it is working fine

```
select org.* from organic org
where (org.data ->> 'bfId') = '785'
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') ->> 'orgType') = 'N'
and (org.data ->> 'instId') = '66656'
and (org.data -> 'accs') @> '["accs_id1"]'
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'reg') @> '["AP"]'
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'desk') @> '["d1"]'
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'country') @> '["C2"]';
```

But while executing the same using spring data Jpa using Native query, it is throwing exception, I tried passing all array parameters as List and JsonArray as String. But in both cases I am facing the same below error

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @> character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

below is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.organic
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT organic_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Sample insert statement below

```
insert into organic(id, data) values
(gen_random_uuid(), '{
  "accs": [
    "accs_id1",
    "accs_id2"
  ],
  "bfId": "785",
  "attributes": {
    "desk": [
      "d1",
      "d2"
    ],
    "reg": [
      "AP",
      "EM"
    ],
    "country": [
      "C1",
      "C2"
    ],
    "orgType": "N"
  },
  "instId": "6656"
}');
```

Sample code on how I am using this query as native query with Spring data Jpa

```
@Query(value = "select org.* from organic org
where (org.data ->> 'bfId') = :bfId
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') ->> 'orgType') = :orgType
and (org.data ->> 'instId') = :instId
and (org.data -> 'accs') @> :accsIds
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'reg') @> :reg
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'desk') @> :desk
and ((org.data -> 'attributes') -> 'country') @> :countaries", nativeQuery = true)
public *returnType* getData(String bfId, String orgType, String instId, List<String> accsIds, List<String> reg, List<String> desk, List<String> countaries)
```

Comment: Don't bind the parameter with the type `character varying`. No idea how to do that with that framework.

Comment: Try using explicit casts in the query. `... and (org.data -> 'attributes' -> 'reg') @> :reg\\:\\:jsonb`. Note the way PostgreSQL's postfix cast operator `::` is [escaped in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982579/spring-boot-data-jpa-and-nativequery-postgres-cast) as `\\:\\:`. Also check if `List<String> reg` produces valid JSON array syntax.